# type error list indices must be integers not str python. Why?

Tags: python, list

This is a code for format printing multiple lists:

```
print("{0[0]:10s} {1[0]:20} {2[0]:5} £{3[0]:6} £{4[0]:<7}".format(gtinlist, desclist, qtylist, pricelist, valuelist))
```

This prints the first value of each list 
But as soon as I change it to:

```
print("{0[0:9]:10s} {1[0:9]:20} {2[0:9]:5} £{3[0:9]:6} £{4[0:9]:<7}".format(gtinlist, desclist, qtylist, pricelist, valuelist))
```

And if I put any number in the place of :9 it does not work.
I don't understand why

Help?

Comment: Might be a good question if it were minimal (one part instead of five) and complete (what's gtinlist?) See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The GTIN-8 product code is a code which is different for every product. It has 8 digits. I made a list called 'gtinlist' to store the user's typed in GTIN-8 codes.

Comment: Nobody cares. Sorry if I was unclear, but what I asked for is an example value. So that this can actually be tested.

Comment: Had you instead posted for example `'{0[0:2]}'.format([5, 6, 7])`, then it would have been a good MCVE question (did you not check out the link I gave you?) that's also interesting to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print the 9th position, you can use

```
"{0[8]:10s}"
```

Using

```
"{0[0:9]:10s}"
```

will tell `format()` to use the key `"0:9"`, which is a string but lists only have integer keys:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str).
```

In python `derp[0:9]` means, to get a slice of the list `derp` from `key 0` to `key 8`. But `format()` does not interpret the `0:9` as python syntax. Format does check if the instance has a `__getitem__` method and passes the key to it.

```
>>> class donk():
...     def __getitem__(self, k):
...           return 5
... 
>>> a = donk()
>>> 'bla{0[3]}'.format(a)
'bla5'
```

If you want to print the first 8 elements here, maybe separated by comma, you may use:

```
", ".join(['{:10s}'.format(a) for a in my_list[0:9])
```

**Additional**: If you want to print all stuff in your arrays on separate lines you can use a for-loop:

```
for i, gt in enumerate(gtinlist):
    print("{:10s} {:20} {:5} £{:6} £{:<7}".format(gt, desclist[i], stylist[i], priceless[i], valueless[i]))
```

In this approach `len(gtinlist) <= len(stylist), len(priceless), len(valueless)`

Comment: thanks, of course.. added an extra sentence that format would have to parse the expression "0:9"

Comment: We have to produce a receipt which is in this format:                                                    universal prod code - description - quantity - price of 1 item - price * quantity                               I do not want to print the eighth line.                                                                           This receipt extends according to the amount of products the user wants.

Comment: why you write {0[0:9]:10s}??

Comment: I thought that would print all nine products i added

Comment: No it doesn't as I described in the answer, it is not possible this way. You need to create loop.

Comment: Thanks, the loop helped

Answer (score 0):

Apparently slicing isn't supported there, only integers (which are turned into ints) and everything else will be interpreted as a string index:

```
>>> class Foo:
        def __getitem__(self, index):
            print('got asked for:', type(index).__name__, repr(index))

>>> x = '{0[3]}'.format(Foo())
got asked for: int 3
>>> x = '{0[3:7]}'.format(Foo())
got asked for: str '3:7'
```

How it would look if a slice were requested:

```
>>> Foo()[3:7]
got asked for: slice slice(3, 7, None)
```

I checked [**the docs**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) but couldn't really find an answer, just that *"an expression of the form '[index]' does an index lookup using `__getitem__()`"*, which could support slicing. But it doesn't even mention that integers will be turned into ints.

Comment: It does not support that slicing,  since it would have parse the string first. It just passes it to __getitem__() so list eventually yields the exception.

Comment: No, it clearly does some parsing/conversion. As you can see in my output, the **int** 3 is asked for, not the string '3'.

Comment: Okay it could do basic parsing like "int(index)" if this does not yield a ValueError it could pass it, otherwise pass it as a string. Something like this may happen, since a['1'] is not supported on lists.

Comment: http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/stringlib/string_format.h the function static `PyObject *get_field_object()` shows the magic.